# Creating 'animated' model.js for ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

Playing around with **ThreeJs** for a project since a few days, I'm now experimenting with rendering animated 3D models. Since I have no background in 3D designs/compatibility in general, I'm not getting all the tradeoffs concerning the different loaders available with this framework.

Nevertheless, I recently discovered that the author of [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphnormals) used directly a [model.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/models/animated/flamingo.js) file. This file is an hash where keys are threejs properties, including  `morphTargets` values containing `verticles` as arrays (I suppose these are keyframes), that, coupled with the `faces` array are used to "animate" from the initial `verticle` array, just like a loop.

After a few hours investigating, I'm wondering how the author could end creating this `flamingo.js`-like file and what would be the best approach to create on myself based on a different 3D model. Also, I'm open to use any software/technology since I'm just looking for a correct workflow to extract this data from any other animated 3D model available online.

Edit: I tried to use the ThreeJS editor to export this data using the geometry option but it doesn't support animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create your animations in a 3D modeling tool like Blender. Depending on your use case, you can use skeleton animation or morph target animation and then export your asset via [glTFExporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter). `glTF` is well supported in `three.js` and the recommended 3D format. Read the following guide for more information about loading 3D models: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Loading-3D-models

Comment: It seems like it is exactly what I was looking for. I'll investigate in that direction. Thank you very much

Comment: All right, I have one more question if you don't mind:
I just used a `gltf` file generator and successfully outputed my blender composition to the browser (thanks to the `glb` file). Nevertheless, I'm missing the blender animation part when the object is rendered. Do you have any pattern to advice me to include the gltf.animation into the render loop? Is there any way to make it work without that within the gltf loading? 
Kind regards

Comment: Anyway, gonna mark this one as answered and open another question.

Comment: Yeah, creating a new question is the right approach at stackoverflow. In the meantime, this post might help if you are trying to play the animation with `three.js`: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gltf-loading-but-not-appearing/911/10?u=mugen87